# Perform Fuzzy match in power query across multiple workbooks or tables without combining them

Tags: excel, merge, powerquery, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

I am simply trying to just do a Fuzzy merge with one Dataset and then another dataset.
The first dataset is fine, But the second dataset is a combination of multiple files which I combine.

Sometimes there is problems with some the files and it is causing an "Container exited unexpectedly with code 0xE0434352. PID: 16928." in power query.

Is there a way I can do A fuzzy match across all the files separately doing a fuzzy merge with dataset1 for each file or table even? Instead of combining each file or table and then doing a fuzzy merge with dataset1?

Thank you.

It works sometimes but there is just some data in some of the files or just one maybe that is causing the issue and I cant identify the file so by doing the fuzzy on each file separately this would allow me to identify the file causing the issue.